# Can you package a WebFilter into a library

Tags: jsp, servlets, annotations, java-ee-6, servlet-filters

And if so how do you do it?.

Yes sounds like my last question. And it is essentially the same problem. I have a `@javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter` which works fine when packaged directly into a war. Now I would like to move the filter in to a library. But if I do so it won't be called any more.

Any pitfalls I have to look out for or is it just plain impossible?

Comment: I haven't used filter annotations yet, so might be off here. Maybe try packaging the class annotated with WebFilter in a jar, and then put that jar inside the war/WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: If you use an EAR then you can package the lib there as well.

Comment: @Martin it is the same thing. I have an ear file and contains a war and ear lib which involved jar s which are used by war s of ear. Webfilter annotation does not effect on web application in case of this class is not belonged to war explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `<web-app metadata-complete="false">`.

This means that the metadata for this web application is not limited to this particular xml (and the classes of the webapp), but can use metadata by 3rd party libraries.

Also take a look at "web fragments". You can define a `web-fragment.xml` in `META-INF` of your jar, and map all servlets and filters there.

[Take a look at this demo](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/servlet_3_0_fragments_and).

Comment: Using both `web-fragment.xml` and `metadata-complete` worked fine. For the benefit of those who might find this question: — 1) I build the library as a standard jar file with maven — 2) I had maven place library in as a standard library the `/lib` directory of the application EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop an empty Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` file in `/META-INF` folder of your JAR project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="yourProjectId" version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

A Servlet 3.0 container will by default scan JARs for presence of `/META-INF/web.xml` file and when present, then scan all classes in the JAR for Servlet 3.0 annotations. No other settings are necessary.

JSF 2.0 has by the way a similar technique with `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`.

Comment: tried this and it didn't work. The file is definitely included in the jar. Tomcat 7.53 Java 60. Oddly enough, it *does* work inside Eclipse. Both the war and jar have the same web.xml with the only difference being the `id` value.