# Using webfilter outside of war

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I've created a webfilter using **javax.servlet.Filter** my code is below

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class KafkaWebFilter implements Filter {
```

This class is within a jar which is under server shared libraries and there are many war's in server. So, I would like to intercept all requests regarding to urlpattern and without putting that jar into the wars lib folder. I have been tried solutions which is mentioned [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947633/can-you-package-a-webfilter-into-a-library). But requests are not being filtered. Sample web.xml of war file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">
```

Any help appreciated